# What are first-login-UI-tutorials/guides called?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, frontend, user-experience

Since English is not my mother language I may not explain correctly but here goes.

In some modern web applications when you register your account and log in for the first time you are greeted with a quick tutorial/guide on how to operate in this application (arrows, text, focus on buttons etc).

I want to know what are they called so I can research on them more, so far when I am Googling for examples "JQuery first login tutorial" or "Web page new account guide" then I only get results for general JQuery tutorials Hello World etc.

Maybe my Google skills are just not that good.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's called `onboarding`. Look into https://introjs.com/

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for. How do I add your comment as answer? Also Why am I being thumbed down?

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. Feel free to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called `onboarding`. A popular Javascript library for this is [introjs](https://introjs.com/),